# ng-html-bind for label that contains checkbox

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, html-sanitizing

I have the following view.It's standard bootstrap for checkboxes,where input is located inside the label

```
<div class="checkbox">
    <label ng-bind-html="vm.trustedHtml">
        <input  type="checkbox" ng-model="vm.isAcknowledged">
    </label>
</div>
```

I need to bind my trustedHtml property,that contains html,on label.But this directive fully replace the content of the label,including the input.How can I avoid it?The only option I see is changing the html and moving the input out of label,but I don't like it.

Comment: Curious what external html you need to stuff into a checkbox label?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, `ng-bind-html` [does not have](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ng/directive/ngBind.js#L139) anything like "place to insert". It's really straightforward.

1. add nested `<span>` and put `ng-bind-html` on it
2. include `<input>` into `vm.trustedHtml`
3. Don't use `ng-bind-html` if you know all variations possible and there are not so many of them: just describe all options with appropriate `ng-if`

Comment: #2 has additional complexity to bind `ng-model` since `ng-bind-html` doesn't run `$compile` by itself